# Firebase - permission denies when fetching users

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class UserService {

    static var currentUserProfile:UserProfile?

    static func observeUserProfile(_ uid:String, completion: @escaping ((_ userProfile:UserProfile?)->())) {
        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")

        userRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            var userProfile:UserProfile?

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let username = dict["username"] as? String,
                let photoURL = dict["photoURL"] as? String,
                let url = URL(string:photoURL) {

                userProfile = UserProfile(uid: snapshot.key, username: username, photoURL: url)
            }

            completion(userProfile)
        })
    }

}
```

My Firebase Realtime Database rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {

      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }
}
```

Where am i getting it all wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that you are actually authenticated at the time you are trying to read from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Did you signed in? You have to sign in first with methods like;

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword
```

or

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously
```

or any other sign in method.

Other way that **I don't recommend (because it gives access to everyone)**, if you want to use it without authentication you can change rules like;

```
{
  "rules": {

      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
}
```

You can change rules after you configure your client. But always consider rules and make your tables according to rules.